# Kill An Application in Android

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I have created a service that creates a timmer task which active every 5 seconds. Then just check the running processes and i have a list of Applications's Packages that i don't want to run. So, when i match them and found any uncessary Application running i launch an Activity called "KillApplication" and pass that package to it to be killed. But it is not killing required Package. Please help me out.

```
public class killApplication extends Activity {

    private DBAdapter db;
    private Context _context;
    String nameOfProcess = "com.android.email";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        _context = this;
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("application")) {
            nameOfProcess = getIntent().getStringExtra("application");
        }
        Log.d("Process Passed", nameOfProcess);
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> listOfProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : listOfProcesses) {
            Log.e("Process Running", process.processName);
            if (process.processName.contains(nameOfProcess)) { // Ends the app
                android.os.Process.killProcess(process.pid);
                Log.d("Killing Process", nameOfProcess + " : " + process.pid);
                manager.restartPackage(process.processName);
                break;
            }
        }
        finish();
    }

}
```

I also have included the permission in Manifest file:

Comment: DON'T DO THIS. Seriously, people, just stop.

Comment: yeah, this will kill your battery.

Comment: Is creating a new `Activity` to do this necessary?

Comment: Fortunately, ordinary developers cannot use `Process.killProcess()` to kill other apps.

Comment: then how i can kill the process ? please help me out.

Comment: I just tried to read the logcat to check any application is launching then tries to kill certain application. But unfortunately, Can't guess from "ActivityManager"to check an activity or process (userdefined/ system) is launching.

Comment: @Fahad you don't. That's how. You, as a third-party developer, are not allowed to terminate other applications.

Comment: It's impressive how people try to abuse the system thinking they can engineer the system better than Google themselves. Almost always, we see *things* like this. Oh my God.

Comment: /me facepalms... well there's only one thing I can say, thank fuq it has not got the same kind of level as Windows where it is more than often abused!

Comment: @kcoppock If that is the case where are all these task managers allowing you to kill any process coming from? I am using Advanced Task Manager and it can terminate any application.

Comment: http://geekfor.me/faq/you-shouldnt-be-using-a-task-killer-with-android/ http://lifehacker.com/5650894/android-task-killers-explained-what-they-do-and-why-you-shouldnt-use-them http://lifehacker.com/5862994/real-world-test-show-that-android-task-killers-are-still-useless http://phandroid.com/2011/06/16/android-psa-stop-using-task-killer-apps-now/

Answer (score 0):

why are you restarting the package you killed? (manager.restartPackage(process.processName);)

and I would say add this:

```
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String.valueOf(process.processName));
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String.valueOf(process.pid));
```

on top of the android.os.process.killprocess line. :)

also dont forget to add this in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

PS: this is too often and this will drain the battery. my 2 cents

Comment: Because this was used to kill processes but right now it should be "manager.killBackgroundProcesses(process.processName);" but this is not working.

Comment: @Fahad Because it requires a system signed certificate. Which you don't, and cannot have, short of building and deploying to your own custom ROM.